# Format a number with suffix of k m b t

Tags: php

I got this function which works ok. But if say value is null then I want it to display 0 instead of "" blank. I added `0 => "0"` to `$abbrevs` but I am not getting the expected result.

My function:

```
function numberConvert($number) {
    $abbrevs = array(12 => "T", 9 => "B", 6 => "M", 3 => "K", 0 => "");
    foreach($abbrevs as $exponent => $abbrev) {
        if($number >= pow(10, $exponent)) {
            $display_num = $number / pow(10, $exponent);
            $decimals = ($exponent >= 3 && round($display_num) < 100) ? 1 : 0;
            return number_format($display_num,$decimals) . $abbrev;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution this?

Comment: `number_format(is_numeric($display_num)?$display_num:0,$decimals).$abbrev;`

Comment: is does not seems to work it displays no number doing so  <?php echo numberConvert(0); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When 10 is raised to any number, the result is always not 0 (this is true for any number and any finite power), so there's no chance `0 >= pow(10,$exponent)`

```
function numberConvert($number) {
    $abbrevs = array(12 => "T", 9 => "B", 6 => "M", 3 => "K", 0 => "");
    foreach($abbrevs as $exponent => $abbrev) {
        if($number >= pow(10, $exponent)) {
            $display_num = $number / pow(10, $exponent);
            $decimals = ($exponent >= 3 && round($display_num) < 100) ? 1 : 0;
            return number_format($display_num,$decimals) . $abbrev;
        }
    }
    return number_format(is_numeric($display_num)?$display_num:0,0); //Not returned yet? Fall back to this.
}
```

Comment: i get u mate. well this seems to be working but then can it not be without decimals it displays as 0.0 but i wanted it to be  like just 0

Comment: Second parameter of number format controls the decimal points . Updated.